# Localizing Google Drive App Icon

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace, chrome-web-store

I'm attempting to localize a google drive app that is hosted in the Google Chrome WebStore. I have localized the app name and description, but would like to localize the app icon as well. I've looked through the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/i18n) and there is no information on how to localize the app icon itself.

```
"icons": {
    "128": "128.png"
},
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear.  Sounds like what you are trying to localize is not the app, but the listing of the app in the marketplace, correct?  So what you want to know is how to show a locale/language-specific icon in the marketplace if, for example, your app needs to have a different logo showing in a different locale/market?